# Use deep learning to predict the continuation of one time series given another

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, predictive-models, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have this problem I'm trying to solve..
I have 2 highly correlated time series (lets call them $A$ & $B$), however past a certain date I only have data for A. I would like to use $A$ to predict what happened to $B$ during that time..

I've seen many times RNNs (mostly LSTM) are being used for time-series prediction, however its always prediction of the same time series... Is there a way to use deep learning (maybe combined with something else) in order to make a prediction for $B$ but still use the useful data we have from $A$ in the process?

To continue this discussion..lets say I have 1000 pairs of time series:
$S_1 = (A_1,B_1),.......,S_{1000} = (A_{1000},B_{1000})$.
In all of them $(A_i,B_i)$ are highly correlated and $A_i$ has 20 (just as an example) more days then $B_i$
These time series are not all going on at the same time but I want to use the knowledge learned from each pair of time series to train a hypothetical model.
There is also some measure of similarity between all $S_i$s to tell given a new series, $S_{1001}$, how relevant is each of the previous $S_i$s towards making prediction for $B_{1001}$'s missing values.
Can I use all this to make a deep learning model to predict $B_{1001}$'s 20 missing values (given $A_{1001}$)?
Is the problem now more suited for deep learning?

Comment: why deep learning? for school or fun? you should start with simple time series regression even if you do AI eventually

Comment: I used Linear regression and it provides good results but I want to see if it can be improved

Comment: I think regression would work just as well for one time series, but maybe for the case of 1000 different time series deep learning can outpreform it

Comment: Not sure I understand the question...each $A_i$ is a independent sequence of length N and $B_i$ is a sequence of length N-20

Comment: Yes I do:) I meant to use the data from $S_1,...,S_{1000}$ to train the model

Comment: For the forecasting period, I only have data from $A_i$ and not from $B_i$

Comment: Can I train the model using only the overlapping parts of $A_i$ and $B_i$ where i ={1,....1000} and then use that along with $A_{1001}$ to make a prediction for the missing data  of  $B_{1001}$?

Comment: Its 2...However, its worth noting that these time series are not all going on at the same time but there is some similarity between them

Comment: Ok, if they're not going at the same time then it's not 2), it's 1). So, for instance when you're forecasting for July 1, 2020 you'll only know $A_{1001}(2020/07/01)$. The values of $A_i(2020/07/01), i=1,\dots,1000$ will not be available. That's a major detail, which you need to add to your question for those who want to help you

Comment: Thanks, I added it in the question:)

Comment: I'm afraid that if other series' predictors A are not available for the forecasting period, then you need strong exogenous assumptions to use the information in the training sample of other series. Otherwise, you are observing only $A_{1001}$ and that's the only one you can use to forecast and train. Exogenous means knowledge that is not in the data set, something that comes from outside, maybe your idea or some theory, something you know about series that is not captured in the data itself

Comment: Yes definitely, the similarity to other time series is not capsulated in the time series itself but in what it represents.